# DynamoDB JsonMarshaller cannot Deserialize List of Object

Tags: java, jackson, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Java class which is the data-model of a table in DynamoDB. I want to use the `DynamoDBMapper` to `save` and `load` items from Dynamo. One member of the class is a `List<MyObject>`. So I used the `JsonMarshaller<List<MyObject>>` to serialize and de-serialize this field.

The list can be successfully serialized by the `JsonMarshaller`. However, when I try to retrieve the entry back and read the list, it throws an exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to MyObject`. It looks like that the `JsonMarshaller` de-serialize the data into the `LinkedHashMap` instead of `MyObject`. How can I get rid of this problem?

The MCVE:

```
// Model.java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "...")
public class Model {
  private String id;
  private List<MyObject> objects;

  public Model(String id, List<MyObject> objects) {
    this.id = id;
    this.objects = objects;
  }

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
  public String getId() { return this.id; }
  public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

  @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = ObjectListMarshaller.class)
  public List<MyObject> getObjects() { return this.objects; }
  public void setObjects(List<MyObject> objects) { this.objects = objects; }
}
```

---

```
// MyObject.java
public class MyObject {
  private String name;
  private String property;

  public MyObject() { }
  public MyObject(String name, String property) {
    this.name = name;
    this.property = property;
  }

  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

  public String getProperty() { return this.property; }
  public void setProperty(String property) { this.property = property; }
}
```

---

```
// ObjectListMarshaller.java
public class ObjectListMarshaller extends JsonMarshaller<List<MyObject>> {}
```

---

```
// Test.java
public class Test {
  private static DynamoDBMapper mapper;

  static {
    AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()
    mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyObject obj1 = new MyObject("name1", "property1");
    MyObject obj2 = new MyObject("name2", "property2");
    List<MyObject> objs = Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2);

    Model model = new Model("id1", objs);
    mapper.save(model); // success

    Model retrieved = mapper.load(Model.class, "id1");
    for (MyObject obj : retrieved.getObjects()) { // exception
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How come youryour marshaller does not implement `DynamoDBMarshaller`? Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the exception?

Comment: Added the MCVE. Since the ``JsonMarshaller`` has implement the ``DynamoDBMarshaller``, you don't need to implement it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Part of the problem here is how the whole DynamoDB Mapper SDK deals with generics. The `interface DynamoDBMarshaller<T extends Object>` has a method `T unmarshall(Class<T> clazz, String obj)`, in which the class to deserialize to is passed as a parameter. The problem is that there is [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339708/627727), and the SDK doesn't provide an easy to deal with this. Jackson is smarter in some cases (the `JsonMarshaller` uses Jackson), which explains why the `serialize` method works correctly.

You need to provide a better implementation for your deserialization. One way you could do this would be to implement the `DynamoDBMarshaller` interface rather than extending the other one (my opinion) so you have better control over how the type is serialized.

Here is an example that is essentially copy/paste of the `JsonMarshaller`, with minor tweaks in deserialization for the `List` to give you an idea:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMarshaller;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

import java.util.List;

import static com.amazonaws.util.Throwables.failure;

public class MyCustomMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<List<MyObject>> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

    @Override
    public String marshall(List<MyObject> obj) {

        try {
            return writer.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw failure(e,
                          "Unable to marshall the instance of " + obj.getClass()
                          + "into a string");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyObject> unmarshall(Class<List<MyObject>> clazz, String json) {
        final CollectionType
            type =
            mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyObject.class);
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw failure(e, "Unable to unmarshall the string " + json
                             + "into " + clazz);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I create my own marshaller in the project and it works well. Thanks.

Comment: @mkobit This works great, but I'm getting the error as DynamoDBMarshaller is deprecated..

Comment: Thanks @Jayendran - I haven't had time to really look back at this question but I'm hoping I eventually will!

Comment: @mkobit : I've posted this as a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688807/alternate-way-to-create-listmyobject-in-dynamodbtable-without-using-dynamodbm) but I forget the answer has already posted below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47153880/7073340)

Comment: How would you do it for mapping List<LocalDateTime> ?

Answer (score 16):

In newer versions simply works with:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "things")
public List<Thing> getThings() {
    return things;
}

public void setThings(final List<Thing> things) {
    this.things = things;
}
```

given that the Thing is adnotated with:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Thing {
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just implemented "Thing" with the usual getters/setters, nothing else required other than adding @DynamoDBDocument and it worked. Best answer imo.

Comment: Which lib's version is 2.3.7? aws-java-sdk-dynamodb?
please mention the lib's name which worked for you.

Comment: It was aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core, which it seems is not directly related to the info above.

Comment: Is there a documentation/guide which explains where do we exactly need the converter? I have to do it by trial and error. I read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html but it provides minimal information..

Comment: How do thing class add properties for generic json...?

Comment: I can confirm. This works with Spring Data DynamoDB in 2022.

Answer (score 5):

DynamoDBMarshaller is now deprecated but I get exactly the same problem with DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson. If you want to store a collection as JSON within a DynamoDBMapper class, use DynamoDBTypeConverted and write a custom converter class (do not use DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson which will not return your collection on unconvert).

Here is the solution using DynamoDBTypeConverted

```
// Model.java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "...")
public class Model {
  private String id;
  private List<MyObject> objects;

  public Model(String id, List<MyObject> objects) {
    this.id = id;
    this.objects = objects;
  }

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
  public String getId() { return this.id; }
  public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

  @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MyObjectConverter.class)
  public List<MyObject> getObjects() { return this.objects; }
  public void setObjects(List<MyObject> objects) { this.objects = objects; }
}
```

-

```
public class MyObjectConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, List<MyObject>> {

    @Override
    public String convert(List<Object> objects) {
        //Jackson object mapper
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String objectsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objects);
            return objectsString;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            //do something
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> unconvert(String objectssString) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<Object> objects = objectMapper.readValue(objectsString, new TypeReference<List<Object>>(){});
            return objects;
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            //do something
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            //do something
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //do something
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple suggestion: Don`t create a new instance of ObjectMapper and use a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Just come through the same issue today and fixed it. It can be fixed by below ways. These might be plenty others too.

**Approach 1:** Using @DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson. It stores the whole `List<Object>` as a single String and retrieves it as `List<Object>`. Add this Annotation to your field DynamoDB will handle the conversion.

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "userDetails")
@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
public List<UserDetail> getUserDetails() {
    return userDetails;
}
```

**Approach 2:** Having a Custom converter. This Stores `List<Object>` as `List<String>` in DB and retrieves them back as `List<Object>`

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "userDetails")
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = UserDetailConverter.class)
public List<UserDetail> getUserDetails() {
    return userDetails;
}

public class UserDetailConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<List<String>, List<UserDetail>> {
    
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    static {
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convert(List<UserDetail> object) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for (UserDetail string : object) {
            try {
                details.add(mapper.writeValueAsString(string));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Unable to serialize object", e);
            }
        }
        return details;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDetail> unconvert(List<String> object) {
        List<UserDetail> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : object) {
            UserDetail detail;
            try {
                detail = mapper.readValue(string, UserDetail.class);
                details.add(detail);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Unable to serialize object", e);
        }
    }
    return details;
}
```

*Hope it helps somebody.*

Answer (score 1):

`Interface DynamoDBMarshaller<T extends Object>` is deprecated already, the replacement is `Interface DynamoDBTypeConverter<S,T>`.

Inside your model class, add the annotation to your list of objects.

```
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = PhoneNumberConverter.class)
   public List<MyObject> getObjects() { return this.objects; }
```

public void setObjects(List objects) { this.objects = objects; }

And this is the implementation of `DynamoDBTypeConverter`.

```
public class PhoneNumberConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, PhoneNumber>
{
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithType(new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});
    @Override
    public String convert(List<MyObject> obj) {
               try {
            return writer.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Unable to marshall the instance of " + obj.getClass()
                    + "into a string");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyObject> unconvert(String s) {
        TypeReference<List<MyObject>> type = new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>() {};
        try {
            List<MyObject> list = mapper.readValue(s, type);
            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to unmarshall the string " + s
                             + "into " + s);
            return null;
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the response by Aleris works fine. In my example, I have a dynamo db table that contains two collections, both of non-primitive classes.

After trying various flavours of DBTypeConverters (taking {String, MyObject}, {Collection, Collection}, {String, Collection}) and also trying Set rather than Collection, by merely annotating the referred to class as a DynamoDBDocument, that I could pass a json array of data for those child classes and the data was persisted correctly.

my "parent class" looks like this (names altered to protect the innocent);

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "SomeTable")
public class ParentClass {

  @NotNull(message = "Key must be specified")
  @Size(min = 12, max = 20)
  @DynamoDBHashKey
  private String key;

  private String type;

  @NotNull(message = "name must be specified.")
  private String name;

  @NotNull(message = "Type code must be specified")
  @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.S)
  private TypeCode typeCode;

  private List<ImageRef> images;

  /**
   * Optional physical dimensions
   */
  private Dimensions productDimensions;

  /**
    * Optional presentations.
    */
  private Set<Presentation> presentations;
}
```

TypeCode is an enumeration.
ImageRef, Presentation and Dimensions classes are all tagged with the DynamoDBDocument annotation.