# JAVA DynamoDB: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I've created CRUD methods but i have some problems with that.

This is my add method code:

```
public Product addProduct(Product content) {
    Product item = new Product();

    item.setName(content.getName());
    item.setCalories(content.getCalories());
    item.setFat(content.getFat());
    item.setCarbo(content.getCarbo());
    item.setProtein(content.getProtein());
    item.setProductKinds(content.getProductKinds());
    item.setAuthor(content.getAuthor());
    item.setMedia(content.getMedia());
    item.setApproved(content.getApproved());


    databaseController.saveTest(item);
    logger.log("Item created");


    return item;
}
```

This is my editProduct method:

```
public Product editProduct(Product product) {
    Product databaseProduct = databaseController.get(Product.class, product.getId());
    databaseProduct.setAllProducts(product);
    databaseController.save(databaseProduct);
    return databaseProduct;
}
```

In model class I think that I have made everything right :

```
package pl.javamill.model.kitchen;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;
import pl.javamill.model.Request;
import pl.javamill.model.common.Author;
import pl.javamill.model.common.AuthorConverter;
import pl.javamill.model.common.Media;
import pl.javamill.model.common.MediaConverter;

import java.util.List;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "product")
public class Product extends Request {

/**
 * Id of kitchen content
 */
private String id;
/**
 * Name of product
 */
private String name;

/**
 * Calories in 100g
 */
private Integer calories;

/**
 * Fat in 100g
 */
private Double fat;

/**
 * Total carbo in 100g
 */
private Double carbo;

/**
 * Total Protein in 100g
 */
private Double protein;

/**
 * Labels of product for example gluten fee product
 */
private List<ProductKind> productKinds;

/**
 * Author of content.
 */
private Author author;

/**
 * Address of content image.
 */
private Media media;

private Boolean approved;

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Calories")
public Integer getCalories() {
    return calories;
}

public void setCalories(Integer calories) {
    this.calories = calories;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Fat")
public Double getFat() {
    return fat;
}

public void setFat(Double fat) {
    this.fat = fat;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Carbo")
public Double getCarbo() {
    return carbo;
}

public void setCarbo(Double carbo) {
    this.carbo = carbo;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Protein")
public Double getProtein() {
    return protein;
}

public void setProtein(Double protein) {
    this.protein = protein;
}

@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = ProductKindConverter.class)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ProductKinds")
public List<ProductKind> getProductKinds() {
    return productKinds;
}

public void setProductKinds(List<ProductKind> productKinds) {
    this.productKinds = productKinds;
}

@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = AuthorConverter.class)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Author")
public Author getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(Author author) {
    this.author = author;
}

@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MediaConverter.class)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Media")
public Media getMedia() {
    return media;
}

public void setMedia(Media media) {
    this.media = media;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Approved")
public Boolean getApproved() {
    return approved;
}

public void setApproved(Boolean approved) {
    this.approved = approved;
}



public void setAllProducts(Product product) {
    if (!getName().equals(product.getName())) {
        setName(product.getName());
    }
    if (!getCalories().equals(product.getCalories())) {
        setCalories(product.getCalories());
    }
    if (!getFat().equals(product.getFat())) {
        setFat(product.getFat());
    }
    if (!getCarbo().equals(product.getCarbo())) {
        setCarbo(product.getCarbo());
    }
    if (!getProtein().equals(product.getProtein())) {
        setProtein(product.getProtein());
    }
    if (!getProductKinds().equals(product.getProductKinds())) {
        setProductKinds(product.getProductKinds());
    }
    if (!getAuthor().equals(product.getAuthor())) {
        setAuthor(product.getAuthor());
    }
    if (!getMedia().equals(product.getMedia())) {
        setMedia(product.getMedia());
    }
    if (!getApproved().equals(product.getApproved())) {
        setApproved(product.getApproved());
    }

}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Product product = (Product) o;

    if (name != null ? !name.equals(product.name) : product.name != null) return false;
    if (calories != null ? !calories.equals(product.calories) : product.calories != null) return false;
    if (fat != null ? !fat.equals(product.fat) : product.fat != null) return false;
    if (carbo != null ? !carbo.equals(product.carbo) : product.carbo != null) return false;
    if (protein != null ? !protein.equals(product.protein) : product.protein != null) return false;
    if (productKinds != null ? !productKinds.equals(product.productKinds) : product.productKinds != null)
        return false;
    if (author != null ? !author.equals(product.author) : product.author != null) return false;
    if (media != null ? !media.equals(product.media) : product.media != null) return false;
    return approved != null ? approved.equals(product.approved) : product.approved == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (calories != null ? calories.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (fat != null ? fat.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (carbo != null ? carbo.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (protein != null ? protein.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (productKinds != null ? productKinds.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (author != null ? author.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (media != null ? media.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (approved != null ? approved.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

ProductKindConventor:

```
public class ProductKindConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, List<ProductKind>> {

@Override
public String convert(List<ProductKind> objects) {
    //Jackson object mapper
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String objectsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objects);
        return objectsString;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        //do something
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<ProductKind> unconvert(String objectsString) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        List<ProductKind> objects = objectMapper.readValue(objectsString, new TypeReference<List<ProductKind>>(){});
        return objects;
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        //do something
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        //do something
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //do something
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Save method in dbcontroller:

```
public void saveTest(Product product){
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(regions).build();
    mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
    mapper.save(product);

}
```

Get product from DB method:

```
public Product getTest(String id) {
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(regions).build();
    mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
    Product retrivedProduct = mapper.load(Product.class, id);
    return retrivedProduct;
}
```

Unit test passed, everything seems to be ok, but when I was using POSTMAN to test, i got some errors. I send product as json and it seems like that:

```
{"id":null,"name":"yoloornotyolo","calories":1000,"fat":400.0,"carbo":20.0,"protein":40.0,"productKinds":["MEAT"],"author":{"name":"Plejer Annołn","id":"testID2"},"media":{"name":"heheszki","url":"http://blabla.pl","mediaType":"IMAGE"},"approved":false}
```

Then I got ""message": "Internal server error"", so I check log file and that what I can see:

> not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted:
> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException

I dont know what is wrong. Can someone explain me what I suppose to do?

Answer (score 8):

It would be useful to see your saveProduct method. You are using DynamoDBMapper annotations but it looks like you are trying to save an item object, not a Product object. Rather than

```
Item item = new Item()
```

Use

```
Product item = new Product();
item.setName...
```

One thing I would mention is that you can offload the handling of your generated id to DyanmoDBMapper using the [DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey annotation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey)

In your model class do this:

```
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
public String getId() { return id; }
public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
```

And then you dont need to handle id in your addProduct method

EDIT: Your saveProduct method should be along the lines of

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
mapper.save(item)
```

I doubt you need to be passing a tablename as that is an annotation on your Product object. You shouldn't be using putItem.

EDIT:
Your saveProduct method should take a Product object, not an item object. Dont use putItem because this doesn't know about your model class. Use DynamoDBMapper save function. You dont need to specify the table name as that's an annotation on your Product class (the table is called 'product'). You should use AmazonDynamoDB for interfacing to DynamoDB. The method below return is void, so you will need to update the addProduct method.

```
public void saveProduct(Product item) {

logger.log("Starting to save an item");

//You need a new method to return an AmazonDynamoDB interface 
AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = getAmazonDynamoDB();
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDB);
mapper.save(item)

logger.log("Item stored");

return saved;
}
```

EDIT:
You build an AmazonDynamoDB interface like this

```
   // Set to your chosen region
   AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
   .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
   .build();
```

EDIT:
DynamoDBMapper only supports certain [data types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html).

You have three complex data types there; productKind, author and media. If you want to store these in your database, you will need to write a [Convertor Class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html) for each one. The convertor class typically define how you convert your object to a string and back again.

EDIT: Your set, ProductKind, will need a convertor that looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793481/dynamodb-jsonmarshaller-cannot-deserialize-list-of-object/47153880#47153880). Just change 'MyObject' to ProductKinds.

Comment: I did that but nothing changed :(

Comment: Updated the answer. I think the problem is you are not building a Product object.

Comment: Ok Thank You, that was theproblem - i changed saveProduct method and now item is stored but now there is another error: "ReturnValues can only be ALL_OLD or NONE (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;

Comment: I think that might be a problem in your saveProduct method. Can you post it? When you save an object you can optionally set return values

Comment: Done but that didn't help, still the same: "ReturnValues can only be ALL_OLD or NONE"

Comment: Are you using DynamoDBMapper in databaseController.saveProduct? I suspect you might be using putItem?

Comment: Yes I'm using putItem, I've edited my post, there is save method which i'm using now, and saveProduct that I've used before (with valid parameter problem)

Comment: I changed method to use DynamoDBMapper but it still not working.. I added new answer, can You check what is wrong?

Comment: Hey, it still doesn't work. I edited my post to actuall code and errors that I've got, can You look at it?

Comment: One of your Product attributes is complex so DynamoDBMapper does not know how to handle it. Please can you post the whole of your Product class.

Comment: I just did it, You can check it

Comment: More info in the edited post. Complex objects (author, media, productKind) need convertor classes.

Comment: I've made 2 converter classes, productKind is an enum so I just used @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum annotation and now I have error: "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item"

Comment: Try changing @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id") to @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id") - You have an property called 'id' but you are referring to it as 'Id'

Comment: It's working! Thank You very mutch but now  I have another problem, my editProduct method (i added that in question) isn't work correctly, I have that error in log file: "Product[ProductKinds]; could not unconvert attribute"

Comment: Great, you're almost there. The final problem is that DynamoDBMapper will convert your set (ProductKinds) into a string OK, but it wont be able to unconvert it when you load it back out of the database. You need another convertor class for ProductKinds. Fortunately I have written an example of this - i have linked to the solution in the answer.

Comment: Yep I'm amost there, I did what u say but now I have "java.lang.NullPointerException
at pl.javamill.model.kitchen.Product.setAllProducts(Product.java:174)" :(((

Comment: I cant tell what line that is as you've updated your class. Maybe you can repost it? The setAllProducts method seems quite strange; do you really mean to copy one Product objects set of properties to another?

Comment: I cant tell what line that is as you've updated your class. Maybe you can repost it? The setAllProducts method seems quite strange; do you really mean to copy one Product objects set of properties to another?

Comment: I just want to change all different fields. That's the line from log where error is: "if (!getProductKinds().equals(product.getProductKinds()))"

Comment: Repost your Product class and your convertor class. I cant see what going on. Did you add the convertor annotation to the ProductKinds getter?

Comment: Yes I did, You can check it now. Adding method works tottaly fine

Comment: This may not be the problem, but you need to remove @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum. ProductKinds is not a enum.

Comment: Also, you are taking one object, checking if any properties are different, and setting them if they are different. Why not just set them without checking? You will get the same result with much less code.

Comment: But ProductKind is an enum

Comment: ProductKind might be, but ProductKinds is not. You are setting ProductKinds (your list) as an enum.

Comment: Ok now I understand, but still i don't know why and I can't figure it out why i'm getting Nullpointerexception

Comment: Write some debug. Print out getProductKinds() and product.getProductKinds() and see what you have.

Comment: Ok i did that and now I see that product that I want to retrieve is null so I think I wrote bad get from DB method. I edited question

Comment: That sounds OK. If you have not instantiated your ProductKinds list in your database item, you will get null. You have a few options, you could stop doing all that checking and just set your database item to the item your are creating (which is what you are doing anyway), or you could check for null in your condition statements.

Comment: Hi, sorry for few days without answer, I got sick.. :( It's almost done, I've added NullPointerExcpetion in setAllProducts and editProduct method is changing every field I want to change except productKinds, productKinds is set to null every time when I'm trying to edit some product in database, even when I don't want to change anything with productKinds field. Any sugestions?

Comment: I would put some debug lines in so you can check whats going on at each stage. However you might want to start with looking at your ProductKinds type. List is an Interface, not an implementation. You can define something as a List but when you create it you need to specify an implementation e.g. List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

Answer (score 7):

It would be useful to have a stack trace for the exception. In the intermediate message it contains the data type and field information which can not be converted.

Usually you do not need to make any convertors, just be sure to have @DynamoDBDocument on all custom classes, and @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum on all custom enums used.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error and it is a bit misleading, all we need to do is use @DynamoDBDocument on the class file of the referenced classes.

For your case, just put this annotation on ProductKind, like this:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
class ProductKind {
    ...
}
```

It should persist into dynamoDB as a map in the product table.

Answer (score 0):

you will run into this error if the mapper class is

> missing a *No-Arg constructor*

or has

> **invalid** *Setters/Getters*

that do not comply with the **camel case convention**.

[(Solved) Error: could not unconvert attribute dynamodb](https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-errors/could-not-unconvert-attribute-dynamodb/#:%7E:text=Error%3A%20could%20not%20unconvert%20attribute%20dynamodb&text=This%20error%20occurs%20in%20Java,assign%20data%20to%20the%20object.)

Answer (score 0):

@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
This is pretty helpful if you want to dump list of objects in dynamo

```
   @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
   @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = ProductKindConverter.class)
   @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ProductKinds")
   public List<ProductKind> getProductKinds() {
       return productKinds;
   }
Instead of this
```

You can do something like this

```
   @DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
   @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ProductKinds")
   public List<ProductKind> getProductKinds() {
       return productKinds;
   }
```