# Dynamodb - Convert enumerator collection

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to convert a collection of enums? I've tried the following without success:

```
@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="myEnums")
private Collection<MyEnum> myEnums;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to save it as collection (i.e. set of strings), please use `@DynamoDBTyped` annotation with `SS` attribute type.

```
@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.SS)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "myEnums")
public Set<MyEnum> getMyEnums() {
    return myEnums;
}
```

Comment: I would be interested to know if this method works out. Definitely the best option if it works. I've found problems with Dynamo 'unconverting' Sets correctly before though (without a custom converter).

Answer (score 2):

myEnums is a Set of enums, not an enum itself.

[DynamoDBTyped](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTyped.html)

> The enum type is only supported by override or custom converter

Because you have a set of enums, you will need to use a customer converter. So remove the `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum` annotation and use a custom converter. You can see an example I have posted before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47153880/4985580). Its a generic Set example but it will work for your enum Set.

EDIT: i.e. use [DynamoDBTypeConverted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverted.html)