# Alternate way to create List<MyObject> in @DynamoDBTable without using dynamodbmarshalling (deprecated)

Tags: java, spring, jackson, amazon-dynamodb

I've followed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30882309/7073340) by creating the *MyCustomMarshaller*.

**MyCustomMarshaller**

```
public class MyCustomMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<List<DemoClass>> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();

    @Override
    public String marshall(List<DemoClass> obj) {

        try {
            return writer.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw failure(e,
                    "Unable to marshall the instance of " + obj.getClass()
                            + "into a string");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<DemoClass> unmarshall(Class<List<DemoClass>> clazz, String json) {
        final CollectionType
                type =
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, DemoClass.class);
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw failure(e, "Unable to unmarshall the string " + json
                    + "into " + clazz);
        }
    }
}
```

**My dynamoDb class**

```
@DynamoDBAttribute
@DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = MyCustomMarshaller.class)
List<DemoClass> Object;
```

**DemoClass**

```
public class DemoClass {

    String name;

    int id;

}
```

All the codes were working great.By the thing is

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMarshalling is
>   **deprecated**

So how can I change my code without using this dynamoDBmarshalling?

Thanks in Advance,
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use [DynamoDBTypeConverter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverter.html)

You can copy my code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47153880/4985580)

For completeness here is the example I used on the linked answer

```
// Model.java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "...")
public class Model {
  private String id;
  private List<MyObject> objects;

  public Model(String id, List<MyObject> objects) {
    this.id = id;
    this.objects = objects;
  }

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
  public String getId() { return this.id; }
  public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

  @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MyObjectConverter.class)
  public List<MyObject> getObjects() { return this.objects; }
  public void setObjects(List<MyObject> objects) { this.objects = objects; }
}
```

-

```
public class MyObjectConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, List<MyObject>> {

    @Override
    public String convert(List<Object> objects) {
        //Jackson object mapper
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String objectsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objects);
            return objectsString;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            //do something
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> unconvert(String objectssString) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<Object> objects = objectMapper.readValue(objectsString, new TypeReference<List<Object>>(){});
            return objects;
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            //do something
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            //do something
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //do something
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that is easier to implement, and you let DynamoDB handle the conversion behind the curtain.

Annotate the field as @DynamoAttribute

```
@DynamoDBAttribute
private MyObjectClass myObject;
```

And the, you annotate the "MyObjectClass" with @DynamoDBDocument

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class MyObjectClass {
....
}
```

And DynamoDB will convert and un-convert the "MyObjectClass myObject" to the JSON shape, even if it's a list / array of objects.