# Java - Retrive a list of heterogeneous data types from dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

This is my table stucture.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="my_table")
public class MyTable {
    private Integer account_id;

    // account_info is a list of kind [1234, "account_name", 0.55]
    private List<Object> account_info; 

@DynamoDBHashKey()
public Integer getAccount_id() { 
    return account_id; 
}
@DynamoDBAttribute
public List<Object> getAccount_info() {
    return account_info;
}
```

I am quite new to java and not able to understand how to write a mapper class for this. All the examples I have seem map it to a list of hashmap like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992305/dynamodb-mapper-annotation-for-object-which-has-list-of-another-object)